# how do I set up NiFi on HTTPS in a container

Tags: docker, https, apache-nifi, rhel8

I want to secure my **NiFi with HTTPS** using the tls-toolkit in standalone mode inside a Docker container, on a remote virtual machine running RHEL 8 (so actually using Podman instead of Docker but using a podman-docker module, I can treat podman as a Docker). I want to use the port 19443 now, but eventually I will be using the 9443.

I have created my simple testing **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM apache/nifi:latest
WORKDIR /opt/nifi/nifi-current
RUN /opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-current/bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n "localhost" -C "CN=user_1, OU=NiFi"
RUN ls localhost/
RUN cp -fv /opt/nifi/nifi-current/localhost/* /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/ # <- first problem, see build
RUN ls conf/
RUN /opt/nifi/nifi-current/bin/nifi.sh start
EXPOSE 19443
USER nifi
```

**HTTP Works**

I have pulled the apache/nifi image and using the command:

```
docker run --name my_nifi -p 19443:19443 -d -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT='19443' my_nifi
```

where the last *my_nifi* is the image tag that I have created from the Dockerfile.

With this container I can connect to
`http://<the remote IP address>:19443/nifi` 
and it works, showing the NiFi page.

**Dockerfile build**

```
docker build -t my_nifi --no-cache .
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
STEP 1: FROM apache/nifi:latest
STEP 2: WORKDIR /opt/nifi/nifi-current
c6788497ae98d998a561aab162f1cded42f17026abe3745e61021826858ff6db
STEP 3: RUN /opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-current/bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n "localhost" -C "CN=user_1, OU=NiFi"
2020/12/30 08:38:15 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandaloneCommandLine: No nifiPropertiesFile specified, using embedded one.
2020/12/30 08:38:16 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandalone: Running standalone certificate generation with output directory ../nifi-current
2020/12/30 08:38:16 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandalone: Generated new CA certificate ../nifi-current/nifi-cert.pem and key ../nifi-current/nifi-key.key
2020/12/30 08:38:16 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandalone: Writing new ssl configuration to ../nifi-current/localhost
2020/12/30 08:38:16 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandalone: Successfully generated TLS configuration for localhost 1 in ../nifi-current/localhost
2020/12/30 08:38:16 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandalone: Generating new client certificate ../nifi-current/CN=user_1_OU=NiFi.p12
2020/12/30 08:38:17 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandalone: Successfully generated client certificate ../nifi-current/CN=user_1_OU=NiFi.p12
2020/12/30 08:38:17 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.toolkit.tls.standalone.TlsToolkitStandalone: tls-toolkit standalone completed successfully
0ce5790c026b4650615a6dc8e5745dece2fe6374104825cf4a9ecdc8dfbbdf46
STEP 4: RUN ls localhost/
keystore.jks  nifi.properties  truststore.jks
85710975c4ed5f1029ad9e7c70b7516e7cf63a9b568e20844d7cf74f8b33f648
STEP 5: RUN cp -fv /opt/nifi/nifi-current/localhost/* /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/
'/opt/nifi/nifi-current/localhost/keystore.jks' -> '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/keystore.jks'
'/opt/nifi/nifi-current/localhost/nifi.properties' -> '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/nifi.properties'
'/opt/nifi/nifi-current/localhost/truststore.jks' -> '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/truststore.jks'
a2b99978024840cc4d2702b31f8f2346398673f31ace9d776af112b1aa3d45ac
STEP 6: RUN ls conf/
authorizers.xml                      login-identity-providers.xml
bootstrap-notification-services.xml  nifi.properties
bootstrap.conf                       state-management.xml
logback.xml                          zookeeper.properties
0adb1c26826936d08f7edd6df604a0689c23cb9e3db47be06f1c9b4ce935a50d
STEP 7: RUN /opt/nifi/nifi-current/bin/nifi.sh start

Java home: /usr/local/openjdk-8
NiFi home: /opt/nifi/nifi-current

Bootstrap Config File: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap.conf


7146d8dc7f891643f42dfd2efef446cedf7b98cf2ecad90ebf6b5de335408b4e
STEP 8: EXPOSE 19443
72f941725ac0c9a66d2c2e0a21286b6db52b3a039c721dccd70234f75dfdd9fe
STEP 9: USER nifi
STEP 10: COMMIT my_nifi
77cf9574d75af00aeed7c6dbacbb853badad82e12f9f448a94f6162df2c1df44
```

In STEP 3 I use the NiFi tls-toolkit to create the jks keys and the new *nifi.properties* file, but:

1. in STEP 5-6, I see the problem that even though the cp command
   says that the files have been copied in the *conf/* folder, they are
   not if I just list the content of that folder.
2. after the build, I ran a new container (`docker run --name my_nifi -p 19443:19443 -d my_nifi`  and even adding `-e NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT='19443'`  is the same) and tried to enter it and manually cp
   the files:

- keystore.jks
- nifi.properties
- truststore.jks

into the conf/ folder and it did copied.

But at the restart of this second container I get this **ERROR**:

```
2020-12-30 08:50:33,022 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log Logging initialized @7671ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2020-12-30 08:50:33,066 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Both the HTTP and HTTPS connectors are configured in nifi.properties. Only one of these connectors should be configured. See the NiFi Admin Guide for more details
2020-12-30 08:50:33,066 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer HTTP connector:   http://8eafc1fa77d0:8080
2020-12-30 08:50:33,066 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer HTTPS connector: https://localhost:9443
2020-12-30 08:50:33,066 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi only supports one mode of HTTP or HTTPS operation, not both simultaneously. Check the nifi.properties file and ensure that either the HTTP hostname and port or the HTTPS hostname and port are empty
2020-12-30 08:50:33,068 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one of the HTTP and HTTPS connectors can be configured at one time
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.configureConnectors(JettyServer.java:825)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.<init>(JettyServer.java:178)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:151)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:72)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:301)
2020-12-30 08:50:33,068 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2020-12-30 08:50:33,069 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

But the **nifi.properties** that has been copied is this one below, which does not have the http values filled:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# Core Properties #
nifi.flow.configuration.file=./conf/flow.xml.gz
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.enabled=true
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.dir=./conf/archive/
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=30 days
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=500 MB
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.count=
nifi.flowcontroller.autoResumeState=true
nifi.flowcontroller.graceful.shutdown.period=10 sec
nifi.flowservice.writedelay.interval=500 ms
nifi.administrative.yield.duration=30 sec
# If a component has no work to do (is "bored"), how long should we wait before checking again for work?
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis
nifi.queue.backpressure.count=10000
nifi.queue.backpressure.size=1 GB

nifi.authorizer.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.login.identity.provider.configuration.file=./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
nifi.templates.directory=./conf/templates
nifi.ui.banner.text=
nifi.ui.autorefresh.interval=30 sec
nifi.nar.library.directory=./lib
nifi.nar.library.autoload.directory=./extensions
nifi.nar.working.directory=./work/nar/
nifi.documentation.working.directory=./work/docs/components

####################
# State Management #
####################
nifi.state.management.configuration.file=./conf/state-management.xml
# The ID of the local state provider
nifi.state.management.provider.local=local-provider
# The ID of the cluster-wide state provider. This will be ignored if NiFi is not clustered but must be populated if running in a cluster.
nifi.state.management.provider.cluster=zk-provider
# Specifies whether or not this instance of NiFi should run an embedded ZooKeeper server
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=false
# Properties file that provides the ZooKeeper properties to use if <nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start> is set to true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties


# H2 Settings
nifi.database.directory=./database_repository
nifi.h2.url.append=;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE

# FlowFile Repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository
nifi.flowfile.repository.wal.implementation=org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog
nifi.flowfile.repository.directory=./flowfile_repository
nifi.flowfile.repository.checkpoint.interval=20 secs
nifi.flowfile.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.flowfile.repository.encryption.key=
nifi.flowfile.repository.retain.orphaned.flowfiles=true

nifi.swap.manager.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.FileSystemSwapManager
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=20000

# Content Repository
nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.FileSystemRepository
nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=1 MB
nifi.content.repository.directory.default=./content_repository
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.retention.period=7 days
nifi.content.repository.archive.max.usage.percentage=50%
nifi.content.repository.archive.enabled=true
nifi.content.repository.always.sync=false
nifi.content.viewer.url=../nifi-content-viewer/
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.content.repository.encryption.key=

# Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.implementation=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.provider.location=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key.id=
nifi.provenance.repository.encryption.key=

# Persistent Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.directory.default=./provenance_repository
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.time=30 days
nifi.provenance.repository.max.storage.size=10 GB
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.time=10 mins
nifi.provenance.repository.rollover.size=100 MB
nifi.provenance.repository.query.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads=2
nifi.provenance.repository.compress.on.rollover=true
nifi.provenance.repository.always.sync=false
# Comma-separated list of fields. Fields that are not indexed will not be searchable. Valid fields are:
# EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, TransitURI, ProcessorID, AlternateIdentifierURI, Relationship, Details
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.fields=EventType, FlowFileUUID, Filename, ProcessorID, Relationship
# FlowFile Attributes that should be indexed and made searchable.  Some examples to consider are filename, uuid, mime.type
nifi.provenance.repository.indexed.attributes=
# Large values for the shard size will result in more Java heap usage when searching the Provenance Repository
# but should provide better performance
nifi.provenance.repository.index.shard.size=500 MB
# Indicates the maximum length that a FlowFile attribute can be when retrieving a Provenance Event from
# the repository. If the length of any attribute exceeds this value, it will be truncated when the event is retrieved.
nifi.provenance.repository.max.attribute.length=65536
nifi.provenance.repository.concurrent.merge.threads=2


# Volatile Provenance Repository Properties
nifi.provenance.repository.buffer.size=100000

# Component Status Repository
nifi.components.status.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.history.VolatileComponentStatusRepository
nifi.components.status.repository.buffer.size=1440
nifi.components.status.snapshot.frequency=1 min

# Site to Site properties
nifi.remote.input.host=localhost
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
nifi.remote.input.http.transaction.ttl=30 sec
nifi.remote.contents.cache.expiration=30 secs

# web properties #
nifi.web.http.host=
nifi.web.http.port=
nifi.web.http.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.https.host=localhost
nifi.web.https.port=9443
nifi.web.https.network.interface.default=
nifi.web.jetty.working.directory=./work/jetty
nifi.web.jetty.threads=200
nifi.web.max.header.size=16 KB
nifi.web.proxy.context.path=
nifi.web.proxy.host=
nifi.web.max.content.size=
nifi.web.max.requests.per.second=30000
nifi.web.should.send.server.version=true

# security properties #
nifi.sensitive.props.key=
nifi.sensitive.props.key.protected=
nifi.sensitive.props.algorithm=PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL
nifi.sensitive.props.provider=BC
nifi.sensitive.props.additional.keys=

nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.jks
nifi.security.keystoreType=jks
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=U/lgE52hjoAhCa0w9KD2XWZeVp1gyNPT5sAY9I0Kyng
nifi.security.keyPasswd=U/lgE52hjoAhCa0w9KD2XWZeVp1gyNPT5sAY9I0Kyng
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=EvHdoccmVKi8dQj51ohiOIYIuR/J/SaMWb176qBIVrY
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=

# OpenId Connect SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.oidc.discovery.url=
nifi.security.user.oidc.connect.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.read.timeout=5 secs
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.id=
nifi.security.user.oidc.client.secret=
nifi.security.user.oidc.preferred.jwsalgorithm=
nifi.security.user.oidc.additional.scopes=
nifi.security.user.oidc.claim.identifying.user=

# Apache Knox SSO Properties #
nifi.security.user.knox.url=
nifi.security.user.knox.publicKey=
nifi.security.user.knox.cookieName=hadoop-jwt
nifi.security.user.knox.audiences=

# Identity Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing user identities such that identities coming from different identity providers
# (certificates, LDAP, Kerberos) can be treated the same internally in NiFi. The following example demonstrates normalizing
# DNs from certificates and principals from Kerberos into a common identity string:
#
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.dn=^CN=(.*?), OU=(.*?), O=(.*?), L=(.*?), ST=(.*?), C=(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.dn=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.dn=NONE
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.pattern.kerb=^(.*?)/instance@(.*?)$
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.value.kerb=$1@$2
# nifi.security.identity.mapping.transform.kerb=UPPER

# Group Mapping Properties #
# These properties allow normalizing group names coming from external sources like LDAP. The following example
# lowercases any group name.
#
# nifi.security.group.mapping.pattern.anygroup=^(.*)$
# nifi.security.group.mapping.value.anygroup=$1
# nifi.security.group.mapping.transform.anygroup=LOWER

# cluster common properties (all nodes must have same values) #
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.missable.max=8
nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=true

# cluster node properties (only configure for cluster nodes) #
nifi.cluster.is.node=false
nifi.cluster.node.address=localhost
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11443
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=10
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=5 sec
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=100
nifi.cluster.firewall.file=
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=

# cluster load balancing properties #
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=1
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=8
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30 sec

# zookeeper properties, used for cluster management #
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=10 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi

# Zookeeper properties for the authentication scheme used when creating acls on znodes used for cluster management
# Values supported for nifi.zookeeper.auth.type are "default", which will apply world/anyone rights on znodes
# and "sasl" which will give rights to the sasl/kerberos identity used to authenticate the nifi node
# The identity is determined using the value in nifi.kerberos.service.principal and the removeHostFromPrincipal
# and removeRealmFromPrincipal values (which should align with the kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal and kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal
# values configured on the zookeeper server).
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=

# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=

# kerberos service principal #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=

# kerberos spnego principal #
nifi.kerberos.spnego.principal=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.keytab.location=
nifi.kerberos.spnego.authentication.expiration=12 hours

# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=

# analytics properties #
nifi.analytics.predict.enabled=false
nifi.analytics.predict.interval=3 mins
nifi.analytics.query.interval=5 mins
nifi.analytics.connection.model.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.status.analytics.models.OrdinaryLeastSquares
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.name=rSquared
nifi.analytics.connection.model.score.threshold=.90
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [the nifi image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi) , you should add specific variables to your docker run command if you want to go https. I will try that, by providing external keystore and truststore.

```sh
docker run --name nifi \
  -v /User/dreynolds/certs/localhost:/opt/certs \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  -e AUTH=tls \
  -e KEYSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/keystore.jks \
  -e KEYSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=QKZv1hSWAFQYZ+WU1jjF5ank+l4igeOfQRp+OSbkkrs \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PATH=/opt/certs/truststore.jks \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=rHkWR1gDNW3R9hgbeRsT3OM3Ue0zwGtQqcFKJD2EXWE \
  -e TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=JKS \
  -e INITIAL_ADMIN_IDENTITY='CN=Random User, O=Apache, OU=NiFi, C=US' \
  -d \
  apache/nifi:latest
```

You could also try to build the image from scratch (ie by downloading nifi from the Dockerfile etc...)

Comment: That is NOT what I want to do though, providing external keystone and truststore, as I have described in the question. I also have tried to write my own Dockerfile as you can see from the first code section in the question, maybe there is something I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: I know, this is not what you want to do. I just tried to give you hints to find where it bugs.
``` FROM apache/nifi:latest ```` means that you are using the official nifi image, so it's not really your own.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean now, but I'm not sure how to work on the Dockerfile that way. Thank you anyway, I have seen the documentation you mentioned in your answer but that was not exactly what I wanted to do as I said.

Comment: Is that also impossible using docker-compose?